# How to use AVAudioNodeTapBlock in a tap in AVAudioEngine.

Tags: swift, avaudioengine

I am trying to install a tap on an AVAudioEngine. I have the current code:

```
    guard let engine = engine, let input = engine.inputNode else {
        print("error!")
        return
    }
    let format = input.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
    let bufferSize = 4096
    input.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: AVAudioFrameCount(bufferSize), format: format, block: )
```

I am unsure on what goes in the block. There isn't much documentation on this. I have found this: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudionodetapblock?language=objc

Could someone explain how to use this?

Thanks,

Feras A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better check the [Swift version of the reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudionodetapblock), if you want to write it in Swift.

> ## Declaration
>
> ```
> typealias AVAudioNodeTapBlock = (AVAudioPCMBuffer, AVAudioTime) -> Void
> ```

You need to pass a closure taking two arguments and returning nothing, so you can write it as:

```
    input.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: AVAudioFrameCount(bufferSize), format: format, block: {buffer, when in
        //...
    })
```

The type of two arguments `buffer` and `when` are `AVAudioPCMBuffer` and `AVAudioTime` respectively.

So, if you want to record the tapped audio into an audio file, you can write something like this:

```
    input.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: AVAudioFrameCount(bufferSize), format: format, block: {buffer, when in
        do {
            try self.audioFile?.write(from: buffer)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    })
```

(Assume `audioFile` is an instance property of type `AVAudioFile?`.)

Anyway, you need to know how to use `AVAudioPCMBuffer`.

---

I'm not sure if `input.inputFormat(forBus: 0)` can be an appropriate format in your case, but that may be another issue.